# finding the derivative of function using scipy.misc.derivative

Tags: python, scipy, derivative

I'm having a problem that the function and its derivative should have the same value.
The function is y=e^x so its derivative should be the same y'=e^x
but when i do it with scipy :

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from math import *

def f(x):
    return exp(x)

def df(x):
    return derivative(f,x)

print(f(1))
print(df(1))
```

it will print the different value
f(1) = 2.178...
df(1) = 3.194...
so it means, e has the different value.
Can anyone explain that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @SevC_10 in his answer, you are missing dx parameter.

I like to show case the use of sympy for derivation operations, I find it much easier in many cases.

```
import sympy
import numpy as np

x = sympy.Symbol('x')

f = sympy.exp(x) # my function e^x
df = f.diff() # y' of the function = e^x

f_lambda = sympy.lambdify(x, f, 'numpy')
df_lambda = sympy.lambdify(x, yprime, 'numpy') # use lambdify

print(f_lambda(np.ones(5)))

# array([2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183])

print(df_lambda(np.ones(5)))

# array([2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183, 2.71828183])

print(f_lambda(np.zeros(5)))

# array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])

print(df_lambda(np.zeros(5)))

# array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])


print(f_lambda(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# array([ 1.        ,  2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692, 54.59815003])

print(df_lambda(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# array([ 1.        ,  2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692, 54.59815003])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `derivative` function has other arguments. From the `help(derivative)`:

```
Parameters
----------
func : function
    Input function.
x0 : float
    The point at which the nth derivative is found.
dx : float, optional
    Spacing.
n : int, optional
    Order of the derivative. Default is 1.
args : tuple, optional
    Arguments
order : int, optional
    Number of points to use, must be odd.
```

As you can see, you didn't specify the `dx` parameter, so this can cause rounding error because the approximate derivative is computed on a larger interval. From the documentation, the default value is 1 (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html).

Simply try to reduce the spacing interval: for example, using `1e-3` I get:

```
2.718281828459045
2.718282281505724
```